# Cannot append my block into not native magento module

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have found lot information about Magento view generation system and this info looks clear but for some reason I have situation where magento patters not works for me. So my company bought module for checkout page and after some time they decided customize it(add some functionality). If we look to magento standarts we see that we never change source code cuz we have lot mechanism for extend it what actually we tried and found some problem. Have I have peace of layout xml which I would like append my custom block:

```
            <block type="ecommerceteam_echeckout/onepage_billing" name="checkout.onepage.address.billing" as="billing_address" template="ecommerceteam/echeckout/billing.phtml">

                <block type="ecommerceteam_echeckout/onepage_billing" name="checkout.onepage.address.billing.form" as="address" template="ecommerceteam/echeckout/billing/address.phtml" />

            </block>
```

And inside billing_address block after address block I would like append my block by follows code:

```
<layout>   
    <checkout_cart_index>
        <reference name="checkout.onepage">
           <block type="kukimi_deliverydate/delivery_date" name="delivery_date" after="address" template="kukimi/deliverydate/delivery/date.phtml" />
       </reference>
   </checkout_cart_index></layout>
```

And this is doesn't works but if I change reference to the content it will work what reason for this? how I can manage situations like this?

Comment: do you want to append the block on cart page Or on onepage or onestep checkout page?

Comment: onepage checkout page module, this module show cart and checkout on same page.

Comment: can you please provide the reference name of `ecommerceteam_echeckout`. how is it? `<ecommerceteam_echeckout_index>`?

Comment: please post the layout xml file of ecommerceteam_echeckout